# Online Voting Theory Resources?

Tags: statistics

I'm trying to learn about voting theory, but so far I have had a spotty education on the topic through random googling. Can anyone recommend a website or book so I can learn more about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using scholar.google.com

This is a complete book devoted too the subject you're interested in

http://books.google.nl/books?hl=nl&lr=&id=eki8mEYLql8C&oi=fnd&pg=PR11&dq=voting+theory&ots=PRKCSNXCoA&sig=H3ZrSpQcsUBblML_MdIs6Yd8ZEw#v=onepage&q=voting%20theory&f=false